# Trouble with Java generics in non-generic class

Tags: java, generics, methods

```
public class method
{
    private static class Foo
    {
        public void hello() { System.out.println("Foo"); }
    }

    private static class Bar
    {
        public void hello() { System.out.println("Bar"); }
    }

    private static <T> void hello(T typ)
    {
        typ.hello();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        hello(foo);
        hello(bar);
    }
}
```

I've looked at the other questions here regarding generics, but despite everything I've seen there and applied to the code I've written, I'm still having problems with my Java code.  I've boiled the problem I'm having to the code above. When I try to compile the codd above, I get the following error:

```
method.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        typ.hello();
           ^
  symbol:   method hello()
  location: variable typ of type T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>hello(T)
```

It could be that I'm tr6ing to do something with generic that they were not designed to do, but based on my understanding of the docum3ntation, this should work.  Of course I read the documentation with the idea that I *could* do something like this, which certainly may have influenced my understanding of it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really trying to duplicate C++ templated member functions
    template<class T> hello(T typ) { }

Comment: If I understand your problem, you have two interfaces Foo and Bar. Both interfaces have a method named hello(). You want to create a method like private static <T> void hello(T typ), where T is either Foo or Bar. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
private static <T> void hello(T typ)
```

T doesn't extend anything that implements a method named "Hello".

Instead, replace it with

```
 private static <T extends ClassThatHasHello> void hello(T type)
```

and the class:

```
 public class ClassThatHasHello {
      public void hello() { }
 }
```

Comment: I see, but in this case I've got multiple classes

Comment: I'm really trying to duplicate C++ templated member functions
    template<class T> hello(T typ) { }

Comment: That's fine, just use an interface instead of a class for ClassThatHasHello. Have your multiple classes implement it

Answer (score 1):

You defined `T` as subtype of Object. without any type restriction. Object has no `hello()` method

You could create an interface or super type for the `Foo and Bar` Then `<T extends SuperType>`

Comment: A supertype might work since I'm trying to write the generic for 2 classes that I didn't write, each of which have the same method

Comment: so you have 4 classes A,B,C,D all have `hello()`, you created a supertype (abstract class/Interface/normal class) `S` it has `hello()` too. let `A-D` extend/implement the `S`. then you can write `<T extends S>` and compiler won't complain about `typ.hello()`

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't write Foo or Bar (which are actually interfaces, not as I've shown them here -- but the error is the same

Comment: then show us your real classes. I think I explained the idea in answer+comment clear enough. pls show your related codes if it still doesn't work there.

Comment: downvote is ok, but pls leave a comment, so that I can learn why it is bad. thx.

Comment: Tried to add code in a comment below, but it came out all in-line, I tried backtick bunch of code backtick and again with a backtick at the beginning and end of each line.  How do I do that?  I'll add code once I figure that out

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `interface`. This works:

```
private interface Hello {
  public void hello();
}

private static class Foo implements Hello {
  @Override
  public void hello() {
    System.out.println("Foo");
  }
}

private static class Bar implements Hello  {
  @Override
  public void hello() {
    System.out.println("Bar");
  }
}

private static <T extends Hello> void hello(T typ) {
  typ.hello();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Bar bar = new Bar();
  hello(foo);
  hello(bar);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to write the generic for 2 classes I did not write (actually interfaces, each of which extend other interfaces, with some overloading)

Comment: In that case you are asking how to dynamically make an object implement an interface - you may be looking for the [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class.

Comment: I think it's just easier to copy/paste the 4 lines for each of the 2 classes in an if statement.  I thought I could save the double maintenence of copy/paste, but java seems to be deficient in that regard as compared to C++ where this would have worked as a templated method

Comment: You may live to regret that decision - that is neither a threat nor a promise. :)

Comment: I most likely will, but adding a whole Proxy class implementation to get around 4 lines of code seems like it's more likely to cause problems given the added complexity.  The architecture on this project leaves a lot to be desired:
Multiple interfaces all implenting the same methods without extending a single, common interface, and where the common interface is implemented, several of the interfaces overload the common methods, so extending the common interface won't work because it's overloaded

Comment: In that case, couldn't I just avoid the generic and write it:
`private void hello(Hello typ)`

Answer (score -2):

you are using generics, and you are trying to call the hello method of type T, but you dont know what type is that. if you are sure it has hello method, use casting

Comment: I don't think casting will work here anyway since I'm passing in 2 different classes and I don't know which it is

Comment: if both have hello method,you can create an interface, make them implement it and then cast to the interface

Comment: They already are interfaces.  I'm just trying avoid a lot of copy paste since both of them implement the same method that I've got to call, giving exactly the same parameters.  Looks like the only solution is copy/paste
I miss C++ :-(

Comment: no its not the only solution, i cant understand why you cant use casting?

Comment: as the interface they both implement

Comment: If I could do that, I wouldn't need a generic, would I?
In any case:
`
    public interface thing2
    {
        public void hello();
    }
    public interface iface1 extends thing1, thing2
    {
        public void hello(String s);
    }

    public interface iface2 extends thing3, thing2
    {
        @Override
        public void hello()
        {
           // some other, different implementation
        }
`
ughhh

Comment: Trying again, with formatting - I can't get formatting code to work in a comment:-(
I hate everything