# Understanding java generic methods

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand generic methods in Java.  Given the following code:

```
public class GenericTest {

    interface Shape {
        public long area();
    }

    public static class Triangle implements Shape
    {
        private long base, height;
        public long area() { return (base * height) / 2; }
    }

    public static  class Rectangle implements Shape
    {
        private long width, height;
        public long area() { return width * height; }
    }

    public <T extends Shape> long area1(T shape)
    {
        return shape.area();
    }

    public long area2(Shape shape)
    {
        return shape.area();
    }

}
```

I can't see/understand why I should use/implement area1 instead of area2 (or vice versa).  Am I missing something?  Don't both methods do the same thing?

It has left me a bit confused regarding generics in Java

Comment: It makes no sense to use generics in this case. Cases in which it *does* make sense are, when you don't know what kind of types you have to **store**.

Comment: In this case as @LukasKnuth said you needn't create a generic version of the area area2() is acceptable; However the current oracle documentation shows great examples on generics. The wildcard generics examples may also help clarify the confusion .. .have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: I was looking at generics as a rough equivalent to C++ templates.  The key thing you pointed out here that is lacking from the other answers (and quite possibly what I as missing is the concept that they are used "when you don't know what type to **store**."
Which is exactly what I was looking for in the answer :-)

Comment: @AhmedMasud, I looked at that information and was under the impression having read that page that the `extends type` portion was not necessary -- which resulted in a great deal of confusion, prompting my previous question: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617622/trouble-with-java-generics-in-non-generic-class)
And seeing that the problem could be resolved without generics at all, I posted this question to determine why I would ever want to use them if I always had to know the type (unlike a C++ template).The answer given by @LukasKnuth that filled in the missing piece of the puzzle

Answer (score 13):

In your example, since the `T` type parameter isn't used in any return values, there is no difference.

However, imagine you had the following methods:

```
public <T extends Shape> T movedShape1(T shape) {
    return shape.move();
}

public Shape movedShape2(Shape shape) {
    return shape.move();
}
```

Here you can see a clear advantage to using `movedShape1()`. You get a more specific type for your return value, without losing any type safety.

Comment: Isn't that still the same?  I don't see the extra type safety, they both return Shape don't they?

Comment: @Xaq: If you have a class `Circle implements Shape`, then calling `movedShape1()` with a `Circle` parameter would return a `Circle`, not a `Shape`. Calling `movedShape2()` with the same `Circle` parameter would yield a `Shape`.

Comment: @Xaq, Keppil is right, and that's super useful when you call a method like that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no good reason for creating the `area1` method.  The `area2` method is preferable.  Generics are to be used when there is a relationship with a specific yet unknown type.  Here, there is nothing specific about the parameter `shape`.  The interface `Shape` already lets us use the `area` method, so we don't care which specific implementation of `Shape` is passed in as `shape`.  So generics aren't needed here.

Use

```
public long area2(Shape shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I this case - Shape is not a (abstract)Class but an Interface, so it has to be implemented (extended in gnerics form of thinking) - I'd say they do exaclty the same, and adding generics there is only shadowing what's really going on